# ScrollEgdeAppearance not taking effect for UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a TableViewcontroller embedded in a UINavigationController. I want the navigation title to be red in color when tableview is not scrolled (contentOffset = 0) and blue color when tableview is scrolled(contentOffset > 0). I thought `scrollEdgeAppearance`  is a perfect candidate to achieve this. However it's not working as expected.

Here's the code, Anything wrong with this or is it not the use case for scrollEdgeAppearance

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appearnce = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearnce.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearnce.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearnce
        
        let appearnce2 = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearnce2.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        appearnce2.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearnce2
    }

   
}
```

[image]